# htaccess for React app using React router hosted on cpanel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, cpanel, client-side

So I have a react single page application that I am hosting on cpanel. I have a pretty common issue from what I have been researching but none of the post in SO have helped me so far.

I am using React Router which I know is purely client-side routing. The problem is when the user refreshes the page on a url such as `https://example.com/privacypolicy` I get the stand `Not Found` error `404`.

My folder structure in cpanel is as follows:

```
home/mysite
public_html
  all the folder from build folder (after npm run build locally)
  index.html(important for the post)
  .htaccess(important for the post)
```

The htaccess file is as follows:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

I was hoping this was going to redirect all the requests to index.html and therefore react would know which component to render once that has been redirected.

It isn't and I'm a bit lost on what I'm doing wrong.

Any help is appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To host ***ReactJS*** website on ***cPanel*** it is important to use ***`homepage`*** attribute in your ***`package.json`***. For example, you can use:

```json
"homepage": "http://example.tld"
```

Once you are done with setting up the ***`homepage`*** attribute, then run the npm build command to compile your code.

```bash
npm run build
```

This command will generate a folder named ***`build`*** in your project's root folder. Then upload the ***`build`*** folder contents to ***cPanel*** and use the below ***`.htaccess`*** file configuration.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]

</IfModule>
```

Comment: The homepage attribute was already set to my website, I tried updating the htaccess to yours and still nothing, any other ideas @udoyhasan

Comment: Can you please share your website url?

Comment: https://www.sintrawelcomecentre.com

Comment: You can try the hash history method as you are hosting on **cPanel**. Instead of using ***`example.com/about`*** you can simply use ***`example.com/#/about`***. For more information please refer to this ***[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writing-manually#:~:text=Bypassing%20the%20problem%20altogether%3A%20Hash%20History)***

Comment: I saw that approach, I'm not the biggest fan but I might end up doing that, thanks for the info

Comment: There is one alternative way. You can use **[Vercel](https://vercel.com)** or **[Netlify](https://netlify.com)** to host your this react app. They both have free plan and will work good with react router and also you don't need to change the url structure.

Comment: yeah, I had it hosted in Netlify and was working well but the email is structured on the company that provides us the cPanel and we can't change

Comment: You can do one thing, you can host the site on Netlify but don't change any nameserver then go to the cPanel DNS zone editor and you will find 2 records for your domain:
***`sintrawelcomecentre.com  A  XX.XX.XX.XX`***  &  ***`www.sintrawelcomecentre.com  CNAME something.tld`***           

Change this to:
***`sintrawelcomecentre.com  A  75.2.60.5`*** &  ***`www.sintrawelcomecentre.com  CNAME  <your_project_subdomain>.netlify.app`***.                 

In this way, you will be able to use the email on cPanel and also can use Netlify to host only the frontend. And all will be functional :)