# React-Router-Dom links not working when manually entered into a URL

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hosting, cpanel

I have created an online drinking game at `lastordersgame.com`. When you go through the navigation on the page to get to the game, it adds `"/drinking_game"` to the url and it all loads fine. However, when you manually type in `"lastordersgame.com/drinking_game"` to play the game it doesn't work and brings up a 404 error.

When I load the website on localhost and type it in the url it works perfectly, but it doesn't on my actual website which I use CPanel to host. I'm not sure if this is a problem with my React code or something I need to fix on CPanel but I can't find a solution anywhere.

Below is the code in my App.js and Index.Js, I'm not sure if I need to add anything to these files or any of my other components to get it to work but there isn't anything in those.

**IndexJS.**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
      <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>
);

reportWebVitals();

);
```

**App.js**

```
import './App.css';
import { Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import Homepage from './components/Homepage';
import DrinkingGame from './components/DrinkingGame';
import Rules from './components/Rules';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className ="App">
      <Routes>
        <Route path='/' element={<Homepage/>} />
        <Route path='/brandons_drinking_game' element={<Homepage/>} />
        <Route path='/homepage' element={<Homepage />} />
        <Route path='/drinking_game' element={<DrinkingGame />} />
        <Route path='/rules' element={<Rules />} />   
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Here is all of the code inside of my Drinking Game component too

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/DrinkingGame.css'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useState, } from 'react';

import BlackGameCards from './BlackGameCards';
import OrangeGameCards from './OrangeGameCards';
import BlueGameCards from './BlueGameCards';
import GreenGameCards from './GreenGameCards';
import RedGameCards from './RedGameCards';
import PinkGameCards from './PinkGameCards';
import YellowGameCards from './YellowGameCards';
import shearer_image from './images/shearer.png'
import speech_bubble from './images/speech_bubble.png'
import WhiteGameCards from './WhiteGameCards';
import PurpleGameCards from './PurpleGameCards';
import rotate_device from './images/rotate_device.png'
import earthquake_image from './images/earthquake_image.png'
import boozenami_image from './images/boozenami.png'
import waves_image from './images/waves_image.png'
import genie_image from './images/genie_image.png'
import reflect_shield from './images/reflect_shield.png'

const DrinkingGame = () => {
    const [num, setNum] = useState(5);
    const [prevNum, setPrevNum] = useState(5);
    const [shearerNum, setShearerNum] = useState(0);
    const storedNames = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("player names"))
    let randomName = storedNames[Math.floor(Math.random() * storedNames.length)];
    const [assignedName, setAssignedName] = useState(0);
    const [shearerStyle, setShearerStyle] = useState("shearer_popup_gone")
    const [speechBubbleStyle, setSpeechBubbleStyle] = useState("speech_bubble_gone")
    const [shearerTextStyle, setShearerTextStyle] = useState("shearer_text_gone")
    const [shearerNameStyle, setShearerNameStyle] = useState("shearer_text_name_gone")
    const [cardStyle, setCardStyle] = useState("game_container")
    const [earthquakeDetailsStyle, setEarthquakeDetailsStyle] = useState("earthquake_container_gone")
    const [earthquakeNum, setEarthquakeNum] = useState(0);
    const [boozenamiDetailsStyle, setBoozenamiDetailsStyle] = useState("earthquake_container_gone")
    const [boozenamiNum, setBoozenamiNum] = useState(0);
    const [genieNum, setGenieNum] = useState(0);
    const [genieDetailsStyle, setGenieDetailsStyle] = useState("earthquake_container_gone")
    const [shieldNum, setShieldNum] = useState(0);
    const [shieldDetailsStyle, setShieldDetailsStyle] = useState("earthquake_container_gone")
    

 *all of my functions for the game itself*

    /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// HTML

    return (
        *all of my html code*
    )
}

export default DrinkingGame
```

My guess is its a client sided thing with React-Router since it works on localhost, but I'm honestly just clueless with it.

Comment: Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72576332/htaccess-for-react-app-using-react-router-hosted-on-cpanel

Comment: can you also add the DrinkingGame component as it gives the more clearity of your code.
As i can see your code is fine enough to run may be it's CPamel issue.

Comment: I already have homepage:lastordersgame.com inside of my package.json file

Comment: @BetterReactDeveloper added my drinking game code, removed any functions and HTML that is purely for making the game function